# labeling in qgis 2.0: if one letter in string is "X"

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a shapefile and I want to label all shapes with a "B" or "A" in its name (string). All others should be ignored.

Like: 
*If [field] contains "B" draw label*

Im using qgis 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN strpos("Column", 'A') > -1 OR strpos("Column", 'B') > -1 THEN "Column" END
```